# Exporting top data to a file

Tags: linux, centos, monitoring

So I've been trying to run the following command to check the consumption by the firefox process.

`top -b | grep "firefox"`

Now I can see the desired output in terminal for it. But now when I try to export it to a file, I'm not able to.
The command I'm running is:

`top -b | grep "firefox" >> filename` or `top -b | grep "firefox" > filename`

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `-n` parm for `top`.  For example,

```
top -b -n 1 | grep "firefox" >> firefox.out
```

Without `-n 1` `top` will keep processing and will never make it to `grep`..
From the man page for `top`:

```
   -n  :Number-of-iterations limit as:  -n number
        Specifies  the  maximum  number of iterations, or frames, top
        should produce before ending.
```

Updated code with a `while` loop.  It will loop forever unless you use
something like `cntr` variable.  Remove the `cntr` code if you want
continuous monitoring:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
not_done=1
cntr=0
# Look for process firefox every 1 seconds
while [ "$not_done" -eq 1 ]
do
  top -b -n 1 | grep "firefox" >> /tmp/firefox.out
  sleep 1
  ((cntr=cntr+1))
  # Addition logic to break out of loop after 10 iterations
  if [ "$cntr" -eq 10 ]
  then
    not_done=0
  fi
  echo "cntr=$cntr"
done
```

Comment: seems to be working fine, but i need it continuously monitoring.
still i can work with this.
thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help out.  You could use a continuous `while` loop with a `sleep` (For timing if needed) and `top` cmd for what you need.

Comment: now i'll have to learn while loop, then.
thanks again.

Comment: I added a script with a `while` loop in my post above for you.  Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add in the command the flag -n
Change the number of processes to show.  You will  be prompted  to  enter the number.

To take a snapshot of a specific process in top utility, execute command with the PID (-p) flag.

> Also i recommed if you want to take snapshots for the process one (PID), and get taking three snapshots of the PID:
> top -p 678 -b -n3 > monitoring.out